# FOSElastica Bundle : retrieving highlights for results

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, highlighting, foselasticabundle

I'm trying to have highlights returned with a global index search with the [FOSElastica Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md).

I have a global index finder in my configuration (yml file):

```
fos_elastica:
  clients:
    default: { host: %elastic_host%, port: %elastic_port% }
  indexes:
    myIndex:
      client: default
      finder: ~
      types: 
       # different types here
```

and I use it as per the doc ([here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md#searching-the-entire-index)) :

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.myIndex');

// Returns a mixed array of any objects mapped
$results = $finder->find('whatever');
```

That works perfectly and returns the expected results.
Now I would like to **highlight the words** found in the results using for instance the *fast vector highlighter* of ES. But I did not find any example or any documentation to do so.

I guess I need to define a more proper \Query object with something like :

```
$query = new \Elastica\Query();
$query->setHighlights(array("whatever"));
$query->setTerm("whatever");

$results = $finder->find($query);
```

But I cannot find any information. Any hint ?

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write the query in JSON first:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "content" : "this is a test"
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "content" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

When it works, translate to Elastica:

```
$matchQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
$matchQuery->setField('content', 'this is a test');

$searchQuery = new \Elastica\Query();
$searchQuery->setQuery($matchQuery);

$searchQuery->setHighlight(array(
    "fields" => array("content" => new \stdObject())
));
```

Comment: Thanks Damien ! Actually the FOSElasticaBundle documentation is quite minimal so I had to dive in the source code to find out what methods I had in hand to translate my Elasticsearch query properly.I ended up with https://gist.github.com/tchapi/1ac99f757e0f336c1e1b which works well. Your tip to write the query first hand helped me though ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code above wasn't working for me but changing `\stdObject()` to `\stdClass()`
made this perfect! (cf. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/62061993640d0894d512587a0cda10ca7eb13c28/Resources/doc/cookbook/attachments.md)

```
$searchQuery = new \Elastica\Query('This is a test');
$searchQuery->setFields(["content"]);

$searchQuery->setHighlight(array(
    "fields" => array("content" => new \stdClass())
));
```